# Multi Statement Request vs separted insert in Teradata

Tags: sql, performance, teradata, jobs, mainframe

is Multi Statement Request more peroformant than multiple separated request in teradata ?

I have a mainframe job that lunch a bteq script that is actually Multi Statement Request as described in the example below :

```
   insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (val1,val2,val3)
 ; insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (val4,val5,val6)
 ; insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (val7,val8,val9);
```

my question is should I keep this one job for the Multi Statement Request or separe it into multipe jobs for each insert ? which way is more performant ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inserting three rows at once should be faster than three separate `insert`s.  There is some overhead to every command that gets executed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your  comment so I should kepp the one job instead of separated requests and jobs

Comment: As Gordon wrote, executing three seperate Inserts requires three round trips to the DBMS vs. one for the MSR. For very short queries like your single-row Inserts a MSR is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BTEQ you can do a batch/bulk insert operation using the `.REPEAT/PACK` command. An example:

```
.set sessions 5
.logon ...
.import vartext ',' file = \\your\file\path\somefile.csv;
.repeat * pack 100
using (val1 integer, val2 varchar(20),val3 varchar(10))
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
values(val1, val2, val3);
```

Even better is using a proper utility like fastload or TPT, but short of that any way you can cram your inserts into a single request the better off you are.